# Searching the right range based on user input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup

For silly reasons, we need to convert our 1 - 4 grading system into 1-100 grades.

My main question here is, is there a better/quicker/more efficient approach than what I'm doing?  B3 on the spreadsheet below shows my approach.

My goal is that a teacher can input how much of the standard they have taught and what the student has met and that the sheet will automatically look at the right conversion chart to pull the grade.

So if the teacher taught the standard up to a 4 and the kid gets a 4 that's 100.  If the teacher taught to 2 and the kid gets a 2 that's still a 100.  Whereas if the teacher taught 4 and the kid gets a 2 that's only a 78.

[Here's the google sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GwpMAFxRCGkv8SHK7jOwNokanSv5C9Q9wKH1TE_M2So/edit#gid=1593150982)

In B3 you can see the direction I'm going.  A long, long set of ifs with vlookups. As you can see I need to do it for each possibility for each assignment.  It *seems* like the kind of thing a computer could be told to do since it's repeating over and over with only slight variation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no scripts needed.

delete everything in B column and use in B3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",, QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A3:A="", 0, 
 IF(C2:AA2=2, IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:AA, 'Conversion Chart'!H3:I, 2, 0)),
 IF(C2:AA2=3, IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:AA, 'Conversion Chart'!E3:F, 2, 0)), 
              IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:AA, 'Conversion Chart'!B3:C, 2, 0)))))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A3:A)-ROW(A3)+1&")")&"")), 
 "select Col2")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done the answer in Google Apps Script as it is easier and straight forward to implement.

Here is the sample data.

[image: sample data]

Here is the sample output.

[image: sample ouptut]

I directly place the converted grade below the score for each assignment. (This can be removed if you want)

Column B contains the average of those converted grades

Average is sum of converted grades over the number of cells in the first row that has 'Assignment' in its value. (In this sample, there are 10)

**NOTE**:

I did add some values to other columns of Standard taught since it is needed for the conversion calculation.

Here is the code with step by step description:

```
function calculateGrade() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Gets data from the sheet named 'IN PROGRESS:Standard Taught'
  var data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('IN PROGRESS:Standard Taught');
  var dataValues = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  // Gets conversion data from the sheet named 'Conversion Chart'
  var conversion = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Conversion Chart');
  var conversionValues = conversion.getRange('B3:I13').getValues();

  // Get second row as our standard taught values
  var standardTaught = dataValues[1];
  // Number of first row cells containing 'Assignment'
  var numAssignments = dataValues[0].filter(function(item){
    if(item.match(/Assignment/)){
      return item;
    }
  }).length;
  var totalScore = 0;

  // Process scores to grade
  dataValues.forEach(function(row, rowIndex){
    // Skip first two rows and succeeding rows that their first columns are blank
    if(rowIndex > 1 && row[0]){
      row.forEach(function(score, colIndex){
        // Skip first two columns since they are not scores
        if(colIndex > 1){
          // Find what conversion table should be the scores are based (4, 3 or 2)
          conversionValues[0].forEach(function(item, index){
            // If standard taught for the column matches the first row of original grade column, that's the conversion table we are using
            if(item == standardTaught[colIndex]){
              // Find in the conversion table we are using the grade value of the score
              for(var i = 0; i < conversionValues.length; i++){
                for(var j = index; j < index + 1; j++){
                  if(conversionValues[i][j] === score){
                    var convertedGrade = conversionValues[i][j + 1];
                    // Set directly below cell of the score to the converted grade value
                    // You can remove the row below if you don't want to see the converted grade below the score
                    data.getRange(rowIndex + 2, colIndex + 1).setValue(convertedGrade);
                    // Skip cells that are not valid numbers/scores
                    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(convertedGrade))){
                      // Add all converted grades for the average
                      totalScore += parseFloat(convertedGrade);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
      // Set row's average score based on the total of converted grades over number of assignments
      data.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 2).setValue(totalScore / numAssignments); 
      // Reset counter for total score for the next rows
      totalScore = 0;
    }
  });
}
```